# How should my simple Rails app be set up on Heroku to be production ready?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn, thin, railsapps

I'm new to Rails and Heroku, and I'm curious about several things regarding production.  Do I need to utilize any worker dynos on a simple rails app that has a little email functionality via Mandrill(no queues have been built on my end), and uses Stripe to charge Users upon signup.  Also, is it completely wrong to not use a Unicorn server in production, or would it ever be reasonable for a very simple app to use Thin in production.  Thanks, I appreciate any guidance!

Comment: How much traffic do you expect for your application? And how important is it for your users to experience snappy performance on the site? If you are expecting hundreds of visitors each hour, or you want the application to respond quickly when an email is sent via the Mandrill API, you should consider adding queuing. Otherwise you don't need a worker dyno. As for Unicorn, Heroku recommends it because it will accommodate more traffic, but with little traffic you could use WEBrick (the deafult) or Thin.

Comment: Thanks!  I've been reading about Phusion Passenger which seems to be quite user friendly.  Do you recommend it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do *not* use WEBrick in production; it is a web server designed for development. You will have a bad time.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server

It sounds like Unicorn or Thin would be fine for your use case. Don't use workers until you have long running actions that can be done in the background.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Heroku has a "production check" feature that can help you (a little) and make some recommendations:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/production-check

Comment: Yeah currently there is no foreseeable need to support much traffic or activity, so I'll keep away from workers for now, and I'll consider Unicorn(currently using Thin).  Thanks for your great input!